# Is it possible to add distortion to the display in the HMD with openvr?

Tags: virtual-reality, openvr

I trying to change the barrel distortion coefficients for the HTC Vive to create a distortion in the HMD. Is OpenVR the best method to do this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, why are you trying to change the distortion? The image should be properly distorted by the middleware (SteamVR, Oculus runtime, OSVR etc.).

Comment: Also, please say what technology and exactly which headset you have issues with

Comment: I have a HTC Vive, The image is properly distorted by SteamVR but I want to make an application that can distort the image so I can show the difference for a class of mine. So I actually have no issue with the headset. I am just wondering is openvr the right thing to do this with!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest to you at this point is to search for OculusRiftEffect.

This is an old plugin for THREE.js that is now useless in normal use because it needed to show you the deformed view on your screen. In most application you don't want that, but you might want to show that to the students. The example was hardcoded to the lenses of Oculus Rift DK2 (or DK1 if you uncomment some stuff inside), but the optics don't differ that much and the effect should be even more visible.

It is removed from their current version, so check out old THREE.js revisions or some stale demos on the internet, and you'll find something. Search something around 3 years back.